# Java - array que vaya creciendo a medida que crece la cantidad de libros

Tags: java, array, poo

Tengo una duda con un ejercicio que dice: Crea una clase Libro con los métodos préstamo, devolución y toString.

Quiero que el vector vaya creciendo a medida que crece la cantidad de libros, pero en `codigo.length`, `codigo` me aparece como que no fue inicializado. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Alguien puede ayudar? ¡Gracias!

```
private String titulo;
private String autor;
private String genero;
private static int codigo;
private static int stock=0;

 public Libro(String titulo, String autor, String genero, int codigo, int stock){

     this.titulo=titulo;
     generaCodigo();
     this.autor=autor;
     this.genero=genero;
 }

 public Libro(String titulo){

//El genera codigo me da error, me dice que cree un objeto

    this("titulo", "desconocido", "a confirmar", generaCodigo(), 0);

 }

public static void generaCodigo (){

//Acá me sale un error como que la variable codigo, en codigo.length no fue inicializada         

    int [] codigo = new int [codigo.length];

      for(int i=0; i>=codigo.length; i++){

         codigo[i]=i;
      }

      stock+=1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Esta línea:

```
int [] codigo = new int [codigo.length];
```

no tiene sentido porque estás intentando crear un array de longitud desconocida. Si descompones esa línea en dos, te darás cuenta del error:

```
int [] codigo; //código está declarado pero no inicializado
codigo = new int [codigo.length];
```

Estás pidiendo que `codigo` sea un array y que su longitud sea igual a su longitud actual. Puesto que actualmente `codigo` no existe, no tiene longitud.

Answer (score 0):

Esta línea está mal:

```
int [] codigo = new int [codigo.length];
```

Le estás dando una longitud desconocida, por que el atributo `codigo` de tu clase libro nunca se inicializa. Otra cosa, no uses el mismo nombre de un atributo de la clase para una variable local, porque haces algo que se llama *hide field* y es mala practica de programación.